# django: DetailView: self.object raises an error when called from the method post, but it does work when called from the method get_context_data

Tags: django, django-generic-views, detailview

I created a class that inherits from `DetailView`, and I overrided the methods `get_context_data` and `post`. What it seems weird as mentioned in the title, is that I can call `self.object` from `get_context_data` but I can't from post so I had to use `self.get_object()` instead. But I would like to understand why? is `self.object` removed by `get_context_data`? so that any method called after it cannot use it or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I used `self.get_object()`, then it worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`post` method doesn't exist by default in `DetailView`, you actually creating it not overriding, so therefore  you need to fetch the object by yourself, the reason it'a available in `get_context_data` is that it's already fetched inside `get` method and saved in `object` property.

Comment: But if object was created already, why isn't it available for my new method post? What I meant is that get_context_data is obviously called first, then self.object is created and saved, so logically it should be available for any method called after get_context_data into the instance of my class, unless the method post is called into another instance, or self.object is cleared before..Does what I said make sense?

Comment: @smarber No no.. if you look at the DetailView source code, `get_context_data` is actually called inside `get` method after the object has been created (inside `get` as well). So you need to do the same thing, when you decide to create your own method (post, put, delete, etc..) you need to grab the object by yourself. Have you looked at ccbv.co.uk reference?